# Compress file to bytes for uploading to SQL Server

Tags: c#, gzip

I am trying to zip files to an SQL Server database table.  I can't ensure that the user of the tool has write priveledges on the source file folder so I want to load the file into memory, compress it to an array of bytes and insert it into my database.

This below does not work.

```
class ZipFileToSql
{
    public event MessageHandler Message;
    protected virtual void OnMessage(string msg)
    {
        if (Message != null)
        {
            MessageHandlerEventArgs args = new MessageHandlerEventArgs();
            args.Message = msg;
            Message(this, args);
        }
    }
    private int sourceFileId;
    private SqlConnection Conn;
    private string PathToFile;
    private bool isExecuting;
    public bool IsExecuting
    {
        get
        { return isExecuting; }
    }
    public int SourceFileId
    {
        get
        { return sourceFileId; }
    }
    public ZipFileToSql(string pathToFile, SqlConnection conn)
    {
        isExecuting = false;
        PathToFile = pathToFile;
        Conn = conn;
    }
    public void Execute()
    {
        isExecuting = true;
        byte[] data;
        byte[] cmpData;
        //create temp zip file
        OnMessage("Reading file to memory");
        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(PathToFile);
        data = new byte[fs.Length];
        ReadWholeArray(fs, data);
        OnMessage("Zipping file to memory");
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true);
        zip.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        cmpData = new byte[ms.Length];
        ReadWholeArray(ms, cmpData);
        OnMessage("Saving file to database");
        using (SqlCommand cmd = Conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = @"MergeFileUploads";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = data;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = cmpData;
            SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter();
            p.ParameterName = "@SourceFileId";
            p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            p.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sourceFileId = (int)p.Value;
        }
        OnMessage("File Saved");
        isExecuting = false;
    }


    private void ReadWholeArray(Stream stream, byte[] data)
    {
        int offset = 0;
        int remaining = data.Length;
        float Step = data.Length / 100;
        float NextStep = data.Length - Step;
        while (remaining > 0)
        {
            int read = stream.Read(data, offset, remaining);
            if (read <= 0)
                throw new EndOfStreamException
                    (String.Format("End of stream reached with {0} bytes left to read", remaining));
            remaining -= read;
            offset += read;
            if (remaining < NextStep)
            {
                NextStep -= Step;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does it not work? Do you get an exception? Which part of the code does not produce the expected results?

Comment: when you have some spare time, check out http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/
years ago I found plenty of reasons that I don't remember now, to switch to this tool. One of them was having bz2 in the database. If I'm not mistaking I was getting a higher compression rate with this one, using bzip2. Too bad it doesn't support LZMA. But gzip is faster.

Comment: Thanks to all volunteers on stackoverflow.  You folks are the best

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code will be easier to debug if you break it down into smaller chunks. In my example, I have provided a Compress and Decompress method. In addition, you do not need to roll your own code to read all bytes out of a `FileStream`. You can simply use `File.ReadAllBytes`. Third, make sure you wrap classes that implement `IDisposable` in a `using` statement.

```
public void Execute()
{
    isExecuting = true;
    byte[] data;
    byte[] cmpData;

    //create temp zip file
    OnMessage("Reading file to memory");

    byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(  PathToFile );

    OnMessage("Zipping file to memory");
    byte[] compressedData = Compress(data);

    OnMessage("Saving file to database");
    SaveToDatabase( compressedData );

    OnMessage("File Saved");
    isExecuting = false;
}

private void SaveToDatabase( byte[] data )
{
     using ( var cmd = Conn.CreateCommand() )
    {
        cmd.CommandText = @"MergeFileUploads";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@File", data );
        cmd.Parameters["@File"].DbType = DbType.Binary;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SourceField");
        var parameter = cmd.Parameters["@SourceField"];
        parameter.DbType = DbType.Int32;
        parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sourceFileId = (int)parameter.Value;
    }
}

private static byte[] Compress( byte[] data )
{
    var output = new MemoryStream();
    using ( var gzip = new GZipStream( output, CompressionMode.Compress, true ) )
    {
        gzip.Write( data, 0, data.Length );
        gzip.Close();
    }
    return output.ToArray();
}
private static byte[] Decompress( byte[] data )
{
    var output = new MemoryStream();
    var input = new MemoryStream();
    input.Write( data, 0, data.Length );
    input.Position = 0;

    using ( var gzip = new GZipStream( input, CompressionMode.Decompress, true ) )
    {
        var buff = new byte[64];
        var read = gzip.Read( buff, 0, buff.Length );

        while ( read > 0 )
        {
            output.Write( buff, 0, read );
            read = gzip.Read( buff, 0, buff.Length );
        }

        gzip.Close();
    }
    return output.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: just when I thought I was decent at coding... Love your style

Comment: Suggestion: put MemoryStream inside "using" block. gzip.Close() is not necessary if you are use "using" block.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.write(VS.100).aspx):

> The write might not occur immediately but is buffered until the buffer size is reached or until the Flush or Close method is called.

So you might try putting a `zip.Flush()` to make sure it flushes the stream.

In addition, when passing your memory stream to your `ReadWholeArray` method, make sure you rewind the stream by setting its `Position` property to `0`.

Comment: +1 for Flush(). ReadWholeArray looks like a re-implementation of MemoryStream.ToArray(); replacing that should help too.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably simplify your code that performs the compression and byte array conversion so something along the lines of the following (Untested, but should be close)

```
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(PathToFile))
  using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress))
  {        
    // This could be replaced with fs.CopyTo(zip); if you are using Framework 4.0
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {        
      zip.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
  }

  // Get the compressed bytes from the memmory stream
  byte[] cmpData = ms.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

BEWARE. MemoryStream will pad your output array with zeros. You need to remember its final position before calling ToArray() and truncate the array to the appropriate size afterwords.

Comment: Are you sure about that? ToArray only returns the bytes used in the memory stream, which I believe will be bytes to the final position. Are you not thinking of GetBuffer, which returns the entire buffer?

Comment: I recall tracing some nasty bug to this awhile ago and ended up having to replace the memory stream with a custom version.